# jQuery filter function playing nice in Firefox but not Chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an `<ul>` that if the child img is missing from the `<li>` it needs to be removed. I am using jQuery 1.4.2. 
I used:

```
$("#itemList ul li").filter(function() {
   return $(this).children("img").length == 0; 
}).remove();
```

This worked fine Firefox, did not throw any errors. All other major browsers threw an error. Using the following did not produce an error:

```
$("#slider ul li").each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).children("img").length == 0)
    {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Is this a bug in jQuery or is there something fundamental missing from my first line of code?

Comment: Not sure the reason for it but your first line is using a different parent id.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you try to achieve:

```
$("#itemList ul li:not(:has(img))").remove();
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to achieve and it can be done in a few forms, but I was just enquiring whether this was a bugin jQuery or a bug in the code, browser, etc. I wasn't really after another way to do it. But thanks anyway.